# Is it possible to create Extension Methods with 2.0 Framework?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I was wondering if there is a way to create extension methods using Visual Studio 2005 and the 2.0 framework?

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static void SomeExtension(this String targetString)
    {

    }
}
```

If there is no way to do this, what would the equivalent be? Just create static methods in some sort of library class?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio 2008 or 2005?

Comment: then you're out of luck.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You **can** create extension methods using .Net framework 2.0, if you use the C# 3.0 compiler and Visual Studio 2008 or greater.

The catch is that you have to add this code to your project:

```
 namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
  public class ExtensionAttribute : Attribute { }
}
```

Basically you need to re declare the ExtensionAttribute in Core.dll (.Net 3.5 +), in your project.

Comment: Ok thanks, so it looks possible with VS2008 and 2.0, but not VS2005 and 2.0, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't possible in .Net 2.0 (without using the C# 3.0 compiler).  You can just create static methods that do exactly the same thing however:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static void SomeExtension(String targetString)
    {
        // Do things
    }
}

// Example use:
StringExtensions.SomeExtension(targetString);
```

In reality extension methods are just a shorthand way of writing the above.

Comment: @Andreas What, if you use the C# 3.0 compiler? That is *definitely* cheating.

Comment: but possible ... so your answer is wrong. it would be true if it states `it is not possible using .net 2.0 compiler`